# CopyFromScreen then resize when taking Screenshot

Tags: c#, .net, resize, screenshot

I am taking screenshot of 4k screen, however I want it to be resized down to 900x540 before copying it into the given `byte[] buffer` to make it faster.

I can't figure out how to resize taken screenshot.

```
   public void Screenshot(byte[] buffer)
        {
//full screen width and height                
using (var BMP = new Bitmap(Params.Width, Params.Height))
            {
                using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(BMP))
                {
                    g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, new Size(Params.Width, Params.Height), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

                    g.Flush();

                    var bits = BMP.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, Params.Width, Params.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
                    Marshal.Copy(bits.Scan0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    BMP.UnlockBits(bits);
                }
            }
        }
```

EDIT: After Stefan's answer I tried that, but this just puts small part of the whole screen in the `buffer`, it just cuts it.

```
 public void Screenshot(byte[] buffer)
    {

        using (var BMP = new Bitmap(Params.TargetWidth, Params.TargetHeight))
        {
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(BMP))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, new Size(Params.WidthSource, Params.HeightSource), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
                g.Flush();

                var bits = BMP.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, Params.TargetWidth, Params.TargetHeight), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
                Marshal.Copy(bits.Scan0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                BMP.UnlockBits(bits);
            }
        }
}
```

this is what ends up in the `buffer`:

[image]

Comment: `to make it faster`; wouldn't the resize operation actually slow it down? Or do you do some other post prosessing?

Comment: Yes I do, it's being encoded to a MJPEG, I want to provide smaller bitmaps to the encoder.

Comment: Ah, yes in that case: there are a lot of examples around the web. The actual implementation might depend a bit on some requirements, e.g.: maintain aspect ratio, resize quality, portrait mode etc. Maybe you should give it a go on [duckduckgo.com](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=resize+bitmap+C%23&t=ffab&atb=v158-4a_&ia=web)

Comment: @Stefan I googled sh.. out of it. Can't find proper solution.

Comment: An example, I'll fix you...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need special requirements you can use one of the [bitmap constructor overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2):

*Update:*

I think you are fetching a partial copy because of this:

```
using (var BMP = new Bitmap(Params.WidthSource, Params.HeightSource))
```

and:

```
var bits = BMP.LockBits(
             new Rectangle(0, 0, Params.WidthSource, Params.HeightSource), 
             ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
```

combined with:

```
//where you have access to the BMP.
var resizedBmp = new Bitmap(BMP,Params.TargetWidth, Params.TargetHeight);
```

Should work :-)

Make sure you dispose it after you're done.

Disposing is important, relying on the garbage collector is not appropriate since, especially when dealing with a lot of images, the GC is to slow and your memory footprint will explode.

Comment: Stefan, thank you for your input, I have tried that, you may have look at the edit of my question, could you please refer to it?

Comment: @Yoda: luck with this, any ?

Comment: I decided to not resize it because it takes too long. I just fed the codec full resolution bitmaps. The size was good enough with XVid codec.